# Unable to install python 3.7 packages Fiona, lxml, pandas, Pillow in mac 10.14.3

Tags: python-3.x, macos, crash, installation, macos-mojave

I was trying to install python 3.7 virtualenv packages in my new mac system with runs mac os 10.14.3. But system installation failed due to environment error

Packages:

```
lxml==3.8.0 
Pillow==4.1.1 
Fiona==1.7.10.post1
pandas==0.20.2
```

I Have attached the full crash report in https://pastebin.com/tzMwwHjB

```
  Failed building wheel for Fiona
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Failed building wheel for pandas
  Failed building wheel for Pillow
Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2897, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2888, in _parsed_pkg_info
    return self._pkg_info
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _pkg_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 503, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 108, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/check.py", line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2635, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2899, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2908, in _compute_dependencies
    for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2890, in _parsed_pkg_info
    metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1410, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1522, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.4.dist-info/METADATA'
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/titus/.virtualenvs/julo-ana/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.4.dist-info/RECORD'
```

Can any one know solution for this. Im trying to fix this for last two days still facing it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the supported version of Python
2. Try the following:

   pip3 install --user package-name (for Python3)
   pip install --user package-name (for Python2)

   Note: Replace package-name with pandas, lxml, etc

Comment: Try "sudo python3 -m pip install lxml"

Comment: Its python version issue I tried with python 3.6 and it worked. the package versions are not supported for 3.7.